# Contrapositive and Contranegative

Tags: meaning

What do **contrapositive** and **contranegative** mean and when are these used with respect to **positive** and/or **negative**?

I specifically have [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9404236v1) article in mind. The word **contranegative** is used in the fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)

> Contraposition is a logical relationship between two propositions, or statements. For example, take the following (true) proposition: "All bats are mammals." We can restate that as "If something is a bat, then it is a mammal." The **contrapositive is**, "If something is not a mammal, then it is not a bat."

I assume the reverse apply to contranegative.

Comment: +1: This is a term from logic. N.B. The term "contranegative" isn't really used, as the *positive* is more about position than polarity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's "contranegative". Neither dictionary.com nor wiktionary gives it, and at this very moment, the word-check is drawing a red line under the word "contranegative".

["Contrapositive"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contrapositive) is anything that has to do with "contraposition", or :

> placed opposite or against

It's used to contrast against something else.

Comment: Well, though not frequent, there are references to contranegative e.g. http://www.jstor.org/pss/20016604

Comment: Hm..... It seems to have some sort of thing to do with mathematics only.

Comment: [NGRAM](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=contrapositive%2C+contranegative&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Ham, or more specifically logic - http://books.google.com/books?id=bQHce6eNhDIC&pg=PA386&dq=contranegative&hl=en&ei=yRMcTsvLCYmt8QPEpb35Bw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=contranegative&f=false ; do notice that contraposition and contrapositive also come from logic.

Answer (score 0):

They're terms from deontic logic (which isn't fun).  I don't think it's really relevant to the topic of the paper, so he's probably mashing words in from other topics of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on context, I think he's just trying to sound smart. He means to say he'll concentrate on the positive rather than the negative.
"Contranegative" doesn't have a definition that I know of.
However, if it was a thing I think it should be the negation of the converse of a conditional statement.
Statement: if A then B: A -> B
Converse: if B then A: B -> A
Negation: it's not the case that if A then B: ~(A -> B)
-> Contranegative: it's not the case that if B then A: ~(B -> A)